# TypeScript custom declaration files for untyped npm modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, typescript2.0

I am consuming a React component called [shiitake](https://github.com/bsidelinger912/shiitake) from npm into my project where I use TypeScript. That library does not have TypeScript declarations so I thought I would write one. The declaration file looks like below (it may not be complete but don't worry about it too much):

```
import * as React from 'react';

declare module 'shiitake' {

    export interface ShiitakeProps {
        lines: number;
    }

    export default class Shiitake extends React.Component<ShiitakeProps, any> { 
    }
}
```

I have put this inside `./typings/shiitake.d.ts` file and on VS Code, I am seeing the below error:

> [ts] Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'shiitake' resolves to an untyped module at 'd:/dev/foo/foobar.foo.Client.Web/node_modules/shiitake/dist/index.js', which cannot be augmented.

On the consumption side, I am still getting the same error even if with the above declaration (since I have `noImplicitAny` compiler switch turned on):

```
/// <reference path="../../../../typings/shiitake.d.ts" />
import * as React from 'react';
import Shiitake from 'shiitake';
```

> [ts] Could not find a declaration file for module 'shiitake'. 'd:/dev/foo/foobar.foo.Client.Web/node_modules/shiitake/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

The standard why of acquiring declaration files for this type of modules is through [`@types/` way](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/10/23/typescript-2-0-acquiring-type-declaration-files) and it works well. However, I cannot get the custom typings work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

The declaration `declare module 'shiitake';` should be in a global scope. i.e. a top-level declaration in a non-module (where a module is a file with at least one top-level `import` or `export`).

A declaration of the form `declare module '...' {  }` in a module is an augmentation. For more details see [Typescript Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation).

So you want this file to look like this:

```
declare module 'shiitake' {

    import * as React from 'react';

    export interface ShiitakeProps {
        lines: number;
    }

    export default class Shiitake extends React.Component<ShiitakeProps, any> { 
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a lot of help, thank you.  For me, the issue was that the `import` statement was outside of the module as opposed to inside.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this like ten times. I spent hours on this, yesterday. I really wish the TypeScript docs were better for this.

Comment: Such a silly problem, and the warnings given are very unclear. VSCode messed this one up for me.

Comment: @dudewad check the username on that post, it looks like at most self-plagiarism (is that banned here?)

Comment: Thanks! My import was outside the module declaration.

Answer (score 7):

In my experience, a definition file will fail in this way if it has any exports **or imports** declared outside the module definition.  If you use an IDE with auto-import, be warned!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem today.

Turns out I paste exported interfaces outside of the module declaration.
The typings file I used as a template had private interfaces at the end of the file.

So my exported interfaces were declared outside of the module declaration.
This is drives typescript compiler nuts.

Once I moved the interfaces into the module boundaries everything got fixed.